# How do I wait for a delegate to return a certain value?

Tags: c#, wait

I am currently using Selenium `WebDriverWait` to wait for things to happend where I don't need the `IWebDriver` functionality. My code looks like this:

```
public static T WaitForNotNull<T>(this IWebDriver driver, Func<T> func)
{
    var result = default(T);

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(d => (result = func()) != null);

    return result;
}

public static void WaitForNull<T>(this IWebDriver driver, Func<T> func)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(d => func() == null);
}
```

Is there a similar construct in .Net which I can use instead of WebDriverWait?

Comment: Are you looking for synchronous wait or asynchronous wait? For synchronous you could use [Task.Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) for asynchronous you have the async and await keywords

Comment: Yes, it's called a `while` loop. Do you see any problem with that?

Comment: just look on the decompiled code of Until method and do the same

Comment: @nvoigt A while loop works but requires some coding.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use an event to notify you when something has happened rather than checking it all the time?

Comment: @Drutten That's why you put it into a method. The method you need seems to be a trivial 10 liner. Is there something I don't see?

Comment: @Magnus yes in most case. but as I see he want the same behaviour of Until and for that he need that the Until method do the work by pulling the result and not pushing it by some signal.

Comment: @nvoigt You may ask the same question about why WebDriverWait exists.

Comment: @GordonAllocman Synchronous wait. Don't see how I could use Task.Wait though?

Comment: `WebDriverWait` exists because someone had the same idea: "oh I need this while loop multiple times in different places, lets refactor it into a method."

Comment: @nvoigt Yes. Maybe someone at Microsoft had the same idea and put the stuff in .Net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

## No

There is no such thing in the .NET Framework, you will have to write such a method yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the original Until implementation ([source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ee654ebb40b15abf6bb172e7f483f703b7e14a56/dotnet/src/support/UI/DefaultWait%7BT%7D.cs#L142)). You can improve it IMO.

And if you don't want to block the calling thread (in case of UI thread), you can easily use the async\await pattern

```
    public TResult Until<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> condition)
    {
        if (condition == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("condition", "condition cannot be null");
        }

        var resultType = typeof(TResult);
        if ((resultType.IsValueType && resultType != typeof(bool)) || !typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(resultType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Can only wait on an object or boolean response, tried to use type: " + resultType.ToString(), "condition");
        }

        Exception lastException = null;
        var endTime = this.clock.LaterBy(this.timeout);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = condition(this.input);
                if (resultType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    var boolResult = result as bool?;
                    if (boolResult.HasValue && boolResult.Value)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!this.IsIgnoredException(ex))
                {
                    throw;
                }

                lastException = ex;
            }

            // Check the timeout after evaluating the function to ensure conditions
            // with a zero timeout can succeed.
            if (!this.clock.IsNowBefore(endTime))
            {
                string timeoutMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Timed out after {0} seconds", this.timeout.TotalSeconds);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.message))
                {
                    timeoutMessage += ": " + this.message;
                }

                this.ThrowTimeoutException(timeoutMessage, lastException);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(this.sleepInterval);
        }
    }
```